# Как вытащить обложку из аудиозаписи?

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Во Вконтакте есть аудиозаписи, которые отображаются с обложками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать так же для плеера на своём сайте. Если кто-то загружает какую-то музыку, то по возможности отображать обложку. Но как это можно сделать? Изначально я планировал вытащить из мета-данных файла имя исполнителя и название песни, сделать поиск в гуглокартинках в формате `имя_исполнителя название_трека album cover`, и взять первую же картинку. Но ведь по такому запросу может отображаться, например, обложка какого-нибудь другого альбома этого же исполнителя. А мне нужна точность. Как можно реализовать такой механизм? В mp3-контейнере, как я понял, не хранятся данные ни об исполнителе, ни обложки альбомов.

Comment: Если их туда сохранить, то хранятся.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну вот я скачал аудиозапись из Вконтакте, у которой была обложка. Как мне вытащить её из mp3-контейнера?

Comment: Лично я, доставал все данные о песне, включая ее обложку путем запроса к странице `vk.com/al_audio.php`. указав ее идентификаторы (и предварительно авторизовавшись), из mp3 не вытащите никак, ибо это обложки ВК хранятся на сервере ВК, а в mp3-контейнерах присутствуют другие обложки, которые ВК не выводит (выводил такие ранее в приложениях на телефоне). upd: берите обложку из мета-данных аудиозаписи.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398013/how-change-mp3-tag-and-photos-with-php/20398115#20398115

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_(метаданные)

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать [getid3](https://www.getid3.org)

```
  <?php
  $Path="mp3 file path";
  $getID3 = new getID3;
  $OldThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($Path);
  if(isset($OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0])){
     $Image='data:'.$OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]['image_mime'].';charset=utf-8;base64,'.base64_encode($OldThisFileInfo['comments']['picture'][0]['data']);
  }
  ?>
  <img id="FileImage" width="150" src="<?php echo @$Image;?>" height="150">
```

Этот код вставляем картинку в HTML в формате **base64**

Comment: Это конечно правильная реализация, но не для ВК, у них обложки устанавливает своя система, которая хранит их потом у себя на сервере. И это не те обложки, которые присутствуют в mp3-контейнере.

Comment: @Let'ssayPie А при чем тут реализация на ВК? Вопрос не о ВК, а о "своем сайте".

Comment: @Эникейщик, данные об аудиозаписи он берет из контакта.

Comment: Ну вопрос в большей части относиться именно в вытаскиванию картинки из MP3. Если же в нем его нет и нужно откуда-то. То скорее нужно создать свою базу с обложками и прикреплять к ID музыки. Но без модерирования такую базу не собрать с Google. Так как картинки часто будут не тем. А еще нужно учитывать, что есть не мало песен с одинаковыми названиями. Google может игнорировать исполнителя и показать более релевантную выдачу.